# Relationship to users table without using the standard 'user_id' column name

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables, one has different columns to record different users names based on authorisation level. but i would like to link to two together. at the moment i have tried the following:

User.php

```
public function approvals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Approval::class);

    }
```

Approval.php

```
public function qs() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'qs');
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
<td>{{ $approval->qs->name }}</td>
```

approvals db structure

```
Schema::create('approvals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');
            $table->integer('stage');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('qs')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('pm')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('rcm')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('doc')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('vpoc')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('vpof')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

users db structure

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Am i going about this all wrong, the qs table column needs to be linking to the users.id?

Comment: What's the foreign key on which you are trying to link users with approvals? Please provide your database structure.

Comment: @zlatan i have updated this will the table structures

Comment: So user should be linked to approvals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `qs` is the user id of the `User` model. So the relation to the `Approval` model is

```
public function qs() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'qs');
    }
```

And in `User` model

```
public function approvals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Approval::class, 'qs');

    }
```

Now you can use

```
{{ $approval->qs->name }}
```

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a _ followed by the name of the primary key column. However, if the foreign key on the Model is not parent_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method.

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: i can understand the logic on how this should work and dont understand why i still get a "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" error

Comment: do you build up the relationship the way i answered?? and one more thing to do is to try changing the relationship name.

Answer (score 0):

If a parent model does not use id as its primary key, or you want to join the child model to a different column, you may pass a third argument to the `belongsTo` method:

```
public function qs() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'foreign_key_here_from_child_table', 'custom_column_from_parent_table');
}
```